# Можно ли как то перетащить информацию с dataGrip с одного компа на другой

Tags: jetbrains, datagrip

Хочу переехать с одного компа на другой,  на одном компе у меня кучу конфигов и баз которые хотелось бы перетащить на новый комп. Есть ли способ перетащить все что есть в дата грип на другой комп?

У меня там нету локальных баз данных, все базы данных находятся на сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас интересуют именно источники данных, вот отличный туториал, как это сделать: https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/05/21/copy-and-share-data-sources-in-datagrip/

Самый простой и короткий способ: выделить все источники данных, нажать Ctrl+C, передать получишвийся текст на новую машину и в новом ДатаГрипе нажать Ctrl+V.

Если нужны консоли и файлы, их придётся перенести руками. Консоли лежат здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Способов очень много. Всё зависит от ваших обстоятельств. Что вам мешает залить исходники в облако(гугл или яндекс диск к примеру) и скачать с нового пк? Также, как вариант, если это регулярная задача, реализовать api для скачивания/загрузки на стороннем сервере.